# Undefined jscript in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have created an ASP.Net application. I am using a javascript which is written in a separate file. I am using `Var myvariableName ={}` in javascript file.

I have included this file in MasterPage and accessing myvariableName in my aspx page.

This is working fine in Google Chrome, however, in IE 8 an unhandled exception is thrown as

> myvariableName is undefined.
>
> the error shows as;
>   0x800a1391 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Common' is undefined

where Common is my javascript variable.

Please assist me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Please check the rendered HTML and see the scope of calling

Comment: In view source I can see that Js file is loaded.

Comment: Var should be var... lowercase, but I don't think that's actually your problem, as you said it works in Chrome. Sounds like something is blocking your JS in IE8. Do you have any browser sniffing js or conditional comments, which may be trying to execute code in IE that doesn't execute in Chrome?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, it is var (lowercase). No I don't have any browser sniffing js

Comment: @VijayBalkawade are there  any errors in the console?

Comment: I am calling a function defined with myvariableName as myvariableName.MyFunction(). At that time it shows myvariableName is undefined.

Comment: @VijayBalkawade: is there any HTML5 specific code written before you declare "myvariableName" variable. Is it failing in later versions of IE (IE9 or IE10)?

Comment: Show more external JS file code and how you link this file...

Comment: is "Var" defined with a capital V in your source code?  because that would be a problem.

Comment: Can you show us example page source on Pastebin or similar please?

Comment: hit f12, use the javascript debugger to set break points and see what happens in your application.

Answer (score 6):

You're probably accessing the variable before your external script is executed.

Be sure to access your variable as soon as the document is fully loaded (i.e. `$(document).ready(function(){...});` if you use jQuery) or try to find out the real execution order with some alert (that [shouldn't be browser-depentent](http://javascript.about.com/od/hintsandtips/a/exeorder.htm), by the way!).

Answer (score 4):

If your code is already in a `document.load` or `$(document).ready(function)` you can always 
handle the variable before acessing it via

```
if (typeof myvariableName !== "undefined") {
    // do stuff
}
```

Some times in IE shit happens and window.load gets screwed specially when async calls are in place.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably getting this error due to a missing semicolon. Change the code to this:

```
var myvariableName = {};
```

Comment: I can see that you have updated your question. You now say that "Common" is your javascript variable. It will be helpful if you include more of your code in your question.

Answer (score 2):

In your asp page, where you access your custom variable, wrap your code with:

```
var myvariableName = {};

window.onload = function(){

  // your code here where you're accessing the variable

};
```